# Android View - Set width dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, width, android-linearlayout

Here's what I need to accomplish, the width of my menu_divider should be equal to the width of my second LinearLayout (wrap_content).

So I need to get the width of the second LinearLayout and set it to my menu_divider.
How do I do that?
Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout   //second LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="174dp"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/menu_divider"
    android:layout_width="174dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#96808080"
    android:minWidth="174dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  I just set the width to match_parent.  Btw, this layout is a for a PopUpWindow so match_parent answers it.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="174dp"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hwlloo nanfkjfouiofr dashjfkhal sdhf"/>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/menu_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```